# How to create or any extension for Express Mail Service and Air mail Shipping method in magento

Tags: magento

How can I enable both Express Mail Service and Air mail Shipping methods. Is there any extension available for Express Mail Service and Air mail Shipping method in Magento, according to weight and price? I have this chart:

```
Weight   Canada      America    

0.5      $720        $730    
1.0      $820        $880    
1.5      $930        $1,030      
2.0      $1,040      $1,130      
2.5      $1,150      $1,200      
3.0      $1,260      $1,260      
3.5      $1,390      $1,390
```

Comment: MatrixRates will do weight or price, to do both there are paid extns.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked about it.
I am trying with this extension but stuck in JSON FORMAT and Formula calculation
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/owebia-shipping-2.html.
Anyone used this extension.can someone help me to make it in json format according to formula.